# Validate form on the tab which is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use [jQuery form validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). I have got a webpage with "save" button and tabs. there is a form in one tab. Here is code for "save" button.

```
$("#save").click(function(){
        $("#optionalform").valid();
});
```

It validates form if the tab with "#optionalform" selected. If it is not selected validation doesn`t work.

Comment: Are you running `$('#optionalform').validate()` somewhere else?

Comment: yes. in document ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is specify that hidden elements should **not** be ignored:

```
$("#optionalform").validate({
    ignore:''
});
```

The default for the ignore option is `':hidden'` which includes all the elements of your form, except when that tab is visible.

See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/NfmWW/